# Multiline textbox entries not seperated

Tags: c#

why other strings other than -ABC12 are not separated?
enter code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace multiline_textbox_seperation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String[] lines = textBox2.Text.Split(',');
            List<string> List = new List<string>();
            List.AddRange(lines);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += List[i] + "\r\n";
            }
            
            List<String> PossitiveList = new List<String> { };
            List<String> NegativeList = new List<String> { };

            for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
            {
                if (List[i].StartsWith("-")) { NegativeList.Add(List[i]); }
                if (List[i].StartsWith("+")) { PossitiveList.Add(List[i]); }
            }

            
            listBox1.DataSource = NegativeList;
            listBox2.DataSource = PossitiveList;

            
        }
        }
    }
```

the result for the string:

```
string input = "-ABC12, +ABC12, -BAC12, -ACC12, +EAC12, -BBC12, -CBC12, +GABC12, +ACC12, +CBC12, +BBC12"
```

typed in textbox2 is:

[image: output]

Comment: You need to `Trim()` each line to get rid of the whitespace, or `Split(new string[]{", "})` (including the space)

Comment: BTW You already have `lines`, why create a `List<string>` also? It is completely unnecessary. And if it is necessary then do `var list = new List<string>(lines);` instead of a loop to add one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simplify a bit with:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var values = new List<string>(textBox2.Text.Split(','))
        .Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
    textBox1.Lines = values.ToArray(); // optional

    var PositiveList = values.Where(x => x.StartsWith("+")).ToList();
    var NegativeList = values.Where(x => x.StartsWith("-")).ToList();

    listBox1.DataSource = NegativeList;
    listBox2.DataSource = PositiveList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely, you have spaces in between.
Instead of doing: `List[i].StartsWith("-")` or `List[i].StartsWith("+")`, do a:

`List[i].Trim().StartsWith("-")`
`List[i].Trim().StartsWith("+")`